# Evenly distribute data-driven tests between test machines

Tags: selenium-webdriver, integration-testing, azure-devops, mstest, data-driven-tests

We currently have quite a few integration and Selenium tests that take a long time to run and they keep growing by the day. They are run nightly using MSTest as Unit testing framework on a couple of test machines within Microsoft tools (Test Agents in Visual Studio Team Services, previously VSO).

Mostly all of them are data-driven using Excel files to store input data, but depending on the test, the number of executions per test varies (e.g. number of rows in Excel data source) from 5-6 to maybe 100 or more in some cases.

Is it possible to distribute the number of executions evenly on the test machines? E.g. The test with 100 rows will run for a couple of hours, long after the smaller data source one will be completed.

NOTE: I know that I could split my larger data sources into smaller ones, but IMHO it kind of breaks the data-driven point.

Comment: how is the execution controlled? A CI server (jenikins team city)...? Just from on top of my head: can be split using test categories, or grids for Selenium (I think).

Comment: Execution is controlled by Visual Studio Team Services, and yes, you can control them by test category, test name, etc. What I'm interested is to be able to split one large data-driven test on run time, without creating multiple tests with smaller data soirces.

Comment: The driven test can’t be split when run it in test agent or visual studio. Also, it is based on the test assemblies to assign tests to different test agents when do test in Vnext build with Run Functional Tests step. So you need to split it to different test assemblies.